# Rails Simple Form font awesome instead of radio buttons breaks form validation flow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, radio-button, font-awesome, simple-form

I’m building a form now with `Rails` & `Simple_form` with validations on the model. In the form I have several collections of radio buttons.

For each of the radio buttons I’m hiding the actual button and adding a `font awesome` icon. I’ve tried this with `f.collection_radio_buttons` and by just replacing the simple_form `f.input` tag with the plain HTML it would otherwise generate. However, after form validation I can only get the values to return and the error messages to display when I stick to this format:

```
<%= f.input field_value, label: false, as: :radio_buttons, collection: [1,2,3,4,5] %>
```

It seems that almost any changes I make to the default radio button causes it to be excluded from the form validation flow. Values are being sent correctly though.

Basically, the form works, values are being retained even after validation failure. What’s going wrong is the error messages are not being displayed and the values aren’t placed back in their fields, so they’re not visible

Basically what I want is a fontawesome icon instead of a radio button, I get the feeling a lot of people have done this before but I can't seem to find many resources online regarding this.

Below is a rough example of the HTML/ERB I was experimenting with. With this the form works, icons are displayed and all seems pretty great until the form is re-rendered after validation failure. Then the values are loaded back into the field, but not displayed for these fields. Any validation errors are also not displayed.

```
<div class="form-group radio_buttons required rating_<%= field_value.to_s %>">
  <input type="hidden" name="rating[<%= field_value.to_s %>]" value="">
  <% (1..5).to_a.each do |number| %>
    <span class="radio">
      <label for="rating_<%= field_value.to_s %>_<%= number %>" id="<%= number %>" data-target=".rating_<%= field_value.to_s %>">
       <input class="radio_buttons optional" type="radio" value=<%= number %> name="rating[<%= field_value.to_s %>]" id="rating_<%= field_value.to_s %>_<%= number %>">
       <i class="fa fa-star fa-2x"></i>
      </label>
    </span>
  <% end %>
</div>
```